# Directive/$http not rendering/working when using back button, with Angular + Require

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, requirejs

I have a directive. It renders (and works) correctly on page load.

If I click and leave the page, and then return using the browsers "back" button, the directive does not show up again.

I am using RequireJS and Angular, and bootstrapping my module.

```
require(['modules...'], function(args) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']); // page "1"
});

require(['modules...'], function(args) {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule2']); // page "2" (completely separate "app")
});
```

My module contains a controller for "page1" (the original page) and a controller for "page2" (the following page.

It looks like the directive is not working because a $http.get is not working when I hit the back button.

Edit

Here is my "controllers.js" file

```
define(['some-modules'], function (args go here) { 

  app.controller('NameOfController', function() {
   // nothing inside here works when I re-visit the page with the back button
  }

});
```

and my "app.js" file:

```
define(['angular', 'angular-animate', 'autocomplete'], function(angular, ngAnimate, autocomplete) {

  var app = angular.module('myModule', ['ngAnimate', 'autocomplete']);

  return app;

});
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? I have a similar issue.

Comment: I ended up not using Angular, but I think the issue was really the back button. If you press the back button, the page gets reloaded from the cache, and usually no server round-trip is done.